# How to change default browser search in google chrome to actually google chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

I am using GoogleChore as a browser, but a few days ago I noticed that if I open new tab in search line I see Yahoo icon

[image]

and if I try to search something it open yahoo search instead of google search. I went to settings in the right up corner and it says that I have a google chrome as my default browser.

[image]

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change your default search engine, not browser. First click three vertical dots at top corner of google chrome, then click Settings. Now from the left pane click Search engine. Then click Manage search engines. Again click the three vertical dots after Google below default search engines and click Make default. Hope that helps